# Lookup using multiple columns and values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet filled with data like below:

```
Gender MS       Age Value
Male   Married  21  1
                22  2
                23  3
                24  4
Male   Single   21  5
                22  6
                23  7
                24  8
Female Married  21  9
                22  10
                23  11
                24  12
```

Now there's this other sheet where the user will only be inputting the column "Gender", "MS", and "Age" values and the excel formula should be fetching the associated factor. Please help me with one such formula.

For e.g. If the user puts Male, Single and 23, the formula should return 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example on your sample data:

[image]

Formula in `G4`:

```
=INDEX(D1:D13,MATCH(1,(ROW(C1:C13)>=MATCH(1,(A1:A13=G1)*(B1:B13=G2),0))*(C1:C13=G3),0))
```

Enter through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Could you please provide a similar formula where there is no "MS" column in the table (and no F2 and G2 cells too). I tried working on it but only ended up with errors. Perhaps if you show me a formula for this case, i might have a better understanding. Also,my bad, there is no value in cell A6 too. P.S. Though the blanks should be avoided but this is the data which cannot be modified.

Comment: You credited me for a working example on the data you have provided and now that's gone.... You can't change around your question. Consider this one answered, and if you have other situations on which you need help, feel free to post another question and tag me for help. @user8107531

Comment: Absolutely. Your credit is back in place. I have created a new question. I am not completely aware of the rules/terms used here.

Comment: Well, if you are not sure, see [ask] a question with a [mcve] @user8107531. I'll be happy to help if you can show the appropriate sample data on your new question and I'll answer it (if I can)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array formula for this. I am assuming the blank data under Gender and MS are filled in.

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:D,MATCH(1,(Sheet2!A2=Sheet1!A:A)*(Sheet2!B2=Sheet1!B:B)*(Sheet2!C2=Sheet1!C:C),0),4)
```

After entering the formula, don't press enter! It is Ctrl+Shift+Enter to make this an array formula.

The formula given compares the values in cells A2, B2 and C2 of Sheet2 with the data held in columns A to D of Sheet1, and outputs the value of the fourth column of the appropriate row.

Comment: Thank you but I am not sure if I understand this formula. Can you please edit this formula to include the following...say Male was entered in Cell D46, Single was entered in E46 and 23 was entered in F46 of Sheet named "Sheet4" and the table shown above happens to be in "Sheet1"

Comment: Replace Sheet2!A2, Sheet2!B2, Sheet2!C2 with Sheet4!D46, Sheet4!E46, Sheet4!F46 respectively. The formula I've given assumes Gender is in column A, MS is in B, Age is in C and Value is in D of Sheet1

Comment: Amazing. Thanks again. But it looks like it works for Age 21 only (with all combinations of gender and MS). When I try putting Age 22 (or something that is not 21) in F46, it shows me #N/A error. Do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: For more details, D46, E46 and F46 are drop-downs. F46 is a drop-down with values 21 through 24. When I choose 21, the above formula works fine. While it doesn't for other values. Additionally, I have populated this drop-down with values from a column in another sheet.

Comment: This wouldn't work if OP leaves blank cells, which he did. I must say it's bad practice to leave blancs, therefore your answer is fine on it's own. But don't do a match on whole columns as it would affect your performence quite significant IMO